# GridControl Navigation

Tags: database, foxpro, gridcontrol

In VFP9 I have a grid control ,witch  show the records from a database table. And also I have a command button wherewith I want to navigate from a row to another. I tried with `thisform.grid1.ActiveRow = thisform.grid1.ActiveRow +1` ,but this doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the VFP documentation, the ActiveRow Property "Specifies the row that contains the active cell in a Grid control. Not available at design time; read-only at run time".

I would do something like this.

```
IF EOF("TableAlias) = .F.
    SKIP 1 IN "TableAlias"
ENDIF
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is how to highlight the actual row when I click on button.